# WPF & Expression studio

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, expression-blend

I've created a WPF application afterwards i added some effects using expression blend.

Now when i try to run the application it wont run without "Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll"

I really want to keep the application in one EXE file. is there anyway to do it?

Comment: assuming that you didn't use it, have you tried to find its dependencies so you can get rid of it ?

Comment: Yes, and I did. Apparently I didn't need the DLL to let the effects stay. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed the DLL into the EXE using [Costura](https://github.com/SimonCropp/Costura). It also provides a VS addin, which allows you to automate the progress of embedding the DLL.